# Load contents on demand in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

When i open a page in ViewPager, it instantiates the neighboring pages. What I would like to achieve is

1.load the contents the page only when the page is on focus.

2.show a loading screen, while i populate the page layout which is on focus and replace the loading screen with page layout after that.

Can someone point me in the right direction to achieve these 2 features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of a good way to solve your first question (I don't believe you can control which pages get loaded, and in which order), but I have something that can help for your second:

Here is an example of a view I created that is loaded in every view of my ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/loading_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ProgressBar 
            style="@style/GenericProgressIndicator"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loading_message_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/loading_message_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

There are two elements nested in the RelativeLayout: a LinearLayout that represents my loading message (including a ProgressBar and a TextView) and a WebView that will hold my content once it is loaded.  The WebView initially has its visibility set to GONE to completely hide it.  In code, I inflate the view and start an AsyncTask to load my data.  Once the data is loaded, I set the LinearLayout's visibility to GONE and the WebView's visibility to VISIBLE.

**onPostExecute in my AsyncTask** - after the data is loaded, hide the loading message and show the data

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void v)
{
    LinearLayout loadingMessage = (LinearLayout)articleLayout.findViewById(R.loading_message);
    WebView articleContent = (WebView)articleLayout.findViewById(R.id.webview);

    [...]
    loadingMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    articleContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Comment: does this process happen every time the page is instantiated? ,if yes, how can i avoid it after loading once?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't seem to be a problem.  I cache my data in a HashMap after loading it, so if it does not exist in the cache, it does not need to re-load it, so it doesn't call the AsyncTask.  It still does show the loadingMessage layout until the articleContent view is populated, but I've never seen it in practice.  Since ViewPager loads off-screen, the only time I see the loading message is when I fling through the views quickly.

Comment: @EricBrynsvold: Can you please elaborate the code of your adapter.I am not getting when to execute the AsyncTask method.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Shashank_Itmaster - the instantiateItem call of the PagerAdapter class is called for every page of your adapter.  This is where I inflate the view and execute my AsyncTask (if the data is not cached) to get the actual data to display in the view.  Are you having trouble getting the data you need?

Comment: Can i just ask if you've ever encountered a problem with the fragment being unloaded by the viewpager before the asynctask completes? 

I've been working with fragments which are using loadermanagers. The fragment implements the LoaderCallbacks and on creating the loader it tells the host activity to show a progress in the actionbar, when loader finishes it tells host activity to hide progress. 

If i fling pages after starting the loader sometimes the progress is never hidden. It seems the fragment implementing the LoaderCallbacks listener has been unloaded by viewpager.

Comment: I haven't done much with fragments, so no, I haven't seen this problem before.  Not sure how to ensure that the fragment does not get unloaded (if in fact, it is being unloaded).